# Leetcode 792: number of matching subsequences, wrong answer

Tags: python

I'm experiencing an issue with [Leetcode #792](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-matching-subsequences/), what I understand from the description is that `abc` possible subsequences are `a`, `b`, `c`, `ab`, `ac`, `bc`, `abc`. Impossible subsequences would be `f`, `gh`, `bb`, `cc`, `ca` ... If this understanding is correct, a simple solution would be keeping count of all letters and where we are in a given string, and if `counts[letter] = 0` or non-existent, a subsequence cannot be formed. Here's the implementation of what I just described, if I'm missing something, pointing it out would be greatly appreciated. Code works for the examples in the description but fails one of the test cases.

```
from collections import Counter


class Solution:
    def numMatchingSubseq(self, s: str, words: List[str]) -> int:
        total = 0
        counts = Counter(s)
        for word in words:
            seen = counts.copy()
            for char in word:
                if not seen.get(char, 0):
                    break
                seen[char] -= 1
            else:
                total += 1
        return total
```

Here's the description of what's required:

> Given a string `s` and an array of strings `words`, return the number of `words[i]` that is a subsequence of `s`. A subsequence of a string is a new string generated from the original string with some characters (can be none) deleted without changing the relative order of the remaining characters. For example, "ace" is a subsequence of "abcde".

Example 1:

```
Input: s = "abcde", words = ["a","bb","acd","ace"]
Output: 3
Explanation: There are three strings in words that are a subsequence of s: "a", "acd", "ace".
```

Example 2:

```
Input: s = "dsahjpjauf", words = ["ahjpjau","ja","ahbwzgqnuk","tnmlanowax"]
Output: 2
```

The failed case:

```
s = "ricogwqznwxxcpueelcobbbkuvxxrvgyehsudccpsnuxpcqobtvwkuvsubiidjtccoqvuahijyefbpqhbejuisksutsowhufsygtwteiqyligsnbqglqblhpdzzeurtdohdcbjvzgjwylmmoiundjscnlhbrhookmioxqighkxfugpeekgtdofwzemelpyjsdeeppapjoliqlhbrbghqjezzaxuwyrbczodtrhsvnaxhcjiyiphbglyolnswlvtlbmkrsurrcsgdzutwgjofowhryrubnxkahocqjzwwagqidjhwbunvlchojtbvnzdzqpvrazfcxtvhkruvuturdicnucvndigovkzrqiyastqpmfmuouycodvsyjajekhvyjyrydhxkdhffyytldcdlxqbaszbuxsacqwqnhrewhagldzhryzdmmrwnxhaqfezeeabuacyswollycgiowuuudrgzmwnxaezuqlsfvchjfloczlwbefksxsbanrektvibbwxnokzkhndmdhweyeycamjeplecewpnpbshhidnzwopdjuwbecarkgapyjfgmanuavzrxricbgagblomyseyvoeurekqjyljosvbneofjzxtaizjypbcxnbfeibrfjwyjqrisuybfxpvqywqjdlyznmojdhbeomyjqptltpugzceyzenflfnhrptuugyfsghluythksqhmxlmggtcbdddeoincygycdpehteiugqbptyqbvokpwovbnplshnzafunqglnpjvwddvdlmjjyzmwwxzjckmaptilrbfpjxiarmwalhbdjiwbaknvcqovwcqiekzfskpbhgxpyomekqvzpqyirelpadooxjhsyxjkfqavbaoqqvvknqryhotjritrkvdveyapjfsfzenfpuazdrfdofhudqbfnzxnvpluwicurrtshyvevkriudayyysepzqfgqwhgobwyhxltligahroyshfndydvffd"
words = ["iowuuudrgzmw","azfcxtvhkruvuturdicnucvndigovkzrq","ylmmo","maptilrbfpjxiarmwalhbd","oqvuahijyefbpqhbejuisksutsowhufsygtwteiqyligsnbqgl","ytldcdlxqbaszbuxsacqwqnhrewhagldzhr","zeeab","cqie","pvrazfcxtvhkruvuturdicnucvndigovkzrqiya","zxnvpluwicurrtshyvevkriudayyysepzq","wyhxltligahroyshfn","nhrewhagldzhryzdmmrwn","yqbvokpwovbnplshnzafunqglnpjvwddvdlmjjyzmw","nhrptuugyfsghluythksqhmxlmggtcbdd","yligsnbqglqblhpdzzeurtdohdcbjvzgjwylmmoiundjsc","zdrfdofhudqbfnzxnvpluwicurrtshyvevkriudayyysepzq","ncygycdpehteiugqbptyqbvokpwovbnplshnzafun","gdzutwgjofowhryrubnxkahocqjzww","eppapjoliqlhbrbgh","qwhgobwyhxltligahroys","dzutwgjofowhryrubnxkah","rydhxkdhffyytldcdlxqbaszbuxs","tyqbvokpwovbnplshnzafunqglnpjvwddvdlmjjyzmwwxzjc","khvyjyrydhxkdhffyytldcdlxqbasz","jajekhvyjyrydhxkdhffyytldcdlxqbaszbuxsacqwqn","ppapjoliqlhbrbghq","zmwwxzjckmaptilrbfpjxiarm","nxkahocqjzwwagqidjhwbunvlchoj","ybfxpvqywqjdlyznmojdhbeomyjqptltp","udrgzmwnxae","nqglnpjvwddvdlmjjyzmww","swlvtlbmkrsurrcsgdzutwgjofowhryrubn","hudqbfnzxnvpluwicurr","xaezuqlsfvchjf","tvibbwxnokzkhndmdhweyeycamjeplec","olnswlvtlbmkrsurrcsgdzu","qiyastqpmfmuouycodvsyjajekhvyjyrydhxkdhffyyt","eiqyligsnbqglqblhpdzzeurtdohdcbjvzgjwyl","cgiowuuudrgzmwnxaezuqlsfvchjflocz","rxric","cygycdpehteiugqbptyqbvokpwovbnplshnzaf","g","surrcsgd","yzenflfnhrptuugyfsghluythksqh","gdzutwgjofowhryrubnxkahocqjzwwagqid","ddeoincygycdpeh","yznmojdhbeomyjqptltpugzceyzenflfnhrptuug","ejuisks","teiqyligsnbqglqblhpdzzeurtdohdcbjvzgjwylmmoi","mrwnxhaqfezeeabuacyswollycgio","qfskkpfakjretogrokmxemjjbvgmmqrfdxlkfvycwalbdeumav","wjgjhlrpvhqozvvkifhftnfqcfjmmzhtxsoqbeduqmnpvimagq","ibxhtobuolmllbasaxlanjgalgmbjuxmqpadllryaobcucdeqc","ydlddogzvzttizzzjohfsenatvbpngarutztgdqczkzoenbxzv","rmsakibpprdrttycxglfgtjlifznnnlkgjqseguijfctrcahbb","pqquuarnoybphojyoyizhuyjfgwdlzcmkdbdqzatgmabhnpuyh","akposmzwykwrenlcrqwrrvsfqxzohrramdajwzlseguupjfzvd","vyldyqpvmnoemzeyxslcoysqfpvvotenkmehqvopynllvwhxzr","ysyskgrbolixwmffygycvgewxqnxvjsfefpmxrtsqsvpowoctw","oqjgumitldivceezxgoiwjgozfqcnkergctffspdxdbnmvjago","bpfgqhlkvevfazcmpdqakonkudniuobhqzypqlyocjdngltywn","ttucplgotbiceepzfxdebvluioeeitzmesmoxliuwqsftfmvlg","xhkklcwblyjmdyhfscmeffmmerxdioseybombzxjatkkltrvzq","qkvvbrgbzzfhzizulssaxupyqwniqradvkjivedckjrinrlxgi","itjudnlqncbspswkbcwldkwujlshwsgziontsobirsvskmjbrq","nmfgxfeqgqefxqivxtdrxeelsucufkhivijmzgioxioosmdpwx","ihygxkykuczvyokuveuchermxceexajilpkcxjjnwmdbwnxccl","etvcfbmadfxlprevjjnojxwonnnwjnamgrfwohgyhievupsdqd","ngskodiaxeswtqvjaqyulpedaqcchcuktfjlzyvddfeblnczmh","vnmntdvhaxqltluzwwwwrbpqwahebgtmhivtkadczpzabgcjzx","yjqqdvoxxxjbrccoaqqspqlsnxcnderaewsaqpkigtiqoqopth","wdytqvztzbdzffllbxexxughdvetajclynypnzaokqizfxqrjl","yvvwkphuzosvvntckxkmvuflrubigexkivyzzaimkxvqitpixo","lkdgtxmbgsenzmrlccmsunaezbausnsszryztfhjtezssttmsr","idyybesughzyzfdiibylnkkdeatqjjqqjbertrcactapbcarzb","ujiajnirancrfdvrfardygbcnzkqsvujkhcegdfibtcuxzbpds","jjtkmalhmrknaasskjnixzwjgvusbozslrribgazdhaylaxobj","nizuzttgartfxiwcsqchizlxvvnebqdtkmghtcyzjmgyzszwgi","egtvislckyltpfogtvfbtxbsssuwvjcduxjnjuvnqyiykvmrxl","ozvzwalcvaobxbicbwjrububyxlmfcokdxcrkvuehbnokkzala","azhukctuheiwghkalboxfnuofwopsrutamthzyzlzkrlsefwcz","yhvjjzsxlescylsnvmcxzcrrzgfhbsdsvdfcykwifzjcjjbmmu","tspdebnuhrgnmhhuplbzvpkkhfpeilbwkkbgfjiuwrdmkftphk","jvnbeqzaxecwxspuxhrngmvnkvulmgobvsnqyxdplrnnwfhfqq","bcbkgwpfmmqwmzjgmflichzhrjdjxbcescfijfztpxpxvbzjch","bdrkibtxygyicjcfnzigghdekmgoybvfwshxqnjlctcdkiunob","koctqrqvfftflwsvssnokdotgtxalgegscyeotcrvyywmzescq","boigqjvosgxpsnklxdjaxtrhqlyvanuvnpldmoknmzugnubfoa","jjtxbxyazxldpnbxzgslgguvgyevyliywihuqottxuyowrwfar","zqsacrwcysmkfbpzxoaszgqqsvqglnblmxhxtjqmnectaxntvb","izcakfitdhgujdborjuhtwubqcoppsgkqtqoqyswjfldsbfcct","rroiqffqzenlerchkvmjsbmoybisjafcdzgeppyhojoggdlpzq","xwjqfobmmqomhczwufwlesolvmbtvpdxejzslxrvnijhvevxmc","ccrubahioyaxuwzloyhqyluwoknxnydbedenrccljoydfxwaxy","jjoeiuncnvixvhhynaxbkmlurwxcpukredieqlilgkupminjaj","pdbsbjnrqzrbmewmdkqqhcpzielskcazuliiatmvhcaksrusae","nizbnxpqbzsihakkadsbtgxovyuebgtzvrvbowxllkzevktkuu","hklskdbopqjwdrefpgoxaoxzevpdaiubejuaxxbrhzbamdznrr","uccnuegvmkqtagudujuildlwefbyoywypakjrhiibrxdmsspjl","awinuyoppufjxgqvcddleqdhbkmolxqyvsqprnwcoehpturicf"]
```

Comment: Which test case does it fail?

Comment: I just added the case to question

Comment: I already did, perhaps refresh the page

Comment: Your function does not take into account that although a character might be available, it only occurs **before** the characters you have already used, and so it actually is not available.

Comment: I already tried another approach without using a dictionary in which I only check `s[i:]` where `i` is the index of the last character looked up in `s`. It still fails the same test case.

Comment: Well, if your question is actually about *that* attempt, and not this one, you should maybe update your question and have it focus on that one.

Comment: That attempt was meant to cross out the possibility you described earlier as I had the same doubts. I thought and still think that decrementing a count for each character is sufficient to avoid looking up characters in the wrong index range. Both approaches don't work anyway so fixing any is fine by me because if I overlooked something, chances are I did in both cases as they fail the same test.

Comment: @trincot I deleted the question because I just tried a brute force approach which works for the test case in question which means you were right probably about looking up characters in the wrong place. I undeleted the question, for you to post your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function does not take into account that although a character might be available, it only occurs before the characters you have already used, and so it actually is not available.

`counts` does not give any clue *where* a letter occurs, so `counts` would be the same whether `s` is "ab" or "ba", yet it is clear that this difference in `s` influences the sub-sequences that are possible.

For example, if `s="ab"` and one of the words is `"ba"` you'll get a false positive.

To solve this, you need to not only know the number of occurrences of a certain letter, but the *indices* of where these occurrences are.

There are several ways to do this. A trivial way is to just look for the next occurrence in `s` based on a given index (using `index` function and its second argument).

Another way, to improve a bit on efficiency, is to have a dictionary with 26 keys: one per lowercase letter of the Latin alphabet. The corresponding values are lists of indices. Then when a word is processed, you could keep track of a current index and use a binary search in the appropriate list of indices to find the next one, and so find an increasing sequence of indices. As soon as no index is available, the word fails as candidate.

Here is a spoiler implementation of that idea:

> `from bisect import bisect
>
>  class Solution:
>      def numMatchingSubseq(self, s: str, words: List[str]) -> int:
>          indexes = {
>              ch: []
>              for ch in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>          }
>          for i, ch in enumerate(s):
>              indexes[ch].append(i)
>          count = 0
>          for word in words:
>              i = -1
>              for ch in word:
>                  lookup = indexes[ch]
>                  k = bisect(lookup, i)
>                  if k == len(lookup):
>                      break
>                  i = lookup[k]
>              else:
>                  count += 1
>          return count`